# What integer $n$ has the property that $5^{96}$ is greater than $n^{72}$ and $5^{96}$ is less than $(n+1)^{72}$?

Tags: inequality

I am learning how to solve inequalities and encountered this problem. I don't know where to start and hope someone can give me a hit or illustrate how to solve the problem. Note: we haven't learned "log". Thank you in advance.

> What integer $n$ has the property that $5^{96}$ is greater than $n^{72}$ and $5^{96}$ is less than $(n+1)^{72}$?

Comment: $n^{72}\leq 5^{96}\leq (n+1)^{72}$ if and only if $\log (n^{72})\leq \log (5^{96})\leq \log((n+1)^{72})$.  Can you continue from here?  Remember that $\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$.

Comment: Hint: $\lfloor 5 ^{4/3} \rfloor$. That said, this is the latest of several quick-fire questions where you showed no work of your own. Please post what you have attempted and what did/didn't work when you ask a question.

Comment: @dxiv, I didn't know where to start. So there is no way for me to show you my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bounding it in terms of powers of $2$'s and $3$'s. Eventually, you'll stumble upon the following:
$$
5^{96} = (5^4)^{24} = 625^{24} > 512^{24} = (2^9)^{24} = (2^3)^{72} = 8^{72}
$$
and:
$$
5^{96} = (5^2)^{48} = 25^{48} < 27^{48} = (3^3)^{48} = (3^2)^{72} = 9^{72}
$$

Comment: I cannot fathom why this question is closed.